# Concatenating many time and date columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, concatenation

I have many date and time column pairs (around 15 each) that share the same prefix, ie. SH or DEL. The columns are all of dtype object, ie. string. All the columns belong to the same `Dataframe`. Here is an example of two such pairs:

```
  SH_DATE         DEL_DATE          SH_TIME      DEL_TIME                

 2020-04-22      2020-04-27         19:42:00     19:11:00           
 2020-04-22      2020-04-25         19:42:00     19:26:00           
 2020-04-24      2020-04-24         09:55:00     09:55:00           
 2020-04-24      2020-04-26         14:27:00     14:27:00
```

I'd like to combine each date/time column pair into a single column. My first inclination was to utilize `LIKE` statements for time and date columns in the `dataframe`, by extracting date/time in their own distinct lists, and then looping over them for the `pd.concat` function, but haven't found a solution yet.

Example of desired output:

```
     SH_DATETIME            DEL_DATETIME                        

 2020-04-22 19:42:00     2020-04-27 19:11:00                
 2020-04-22 19:42:00     2020-04-25 19:26:00                    
 2020-04-24 09:55:00     2020-04-24 09:55:00                    
 2020-04-24 14:27:00     2020-04-26 14:27:00
```

Comment: your question isn't very clear.  Can you provide an example of expected output?

Comment: are your date and time columns in the same table?  I'm not sure why `LIKE` is part of the thinking

Comment: Are those columns holding strings?

Comment: I have edited the question, hopefully it is more precise. I tried to make it short and sweet, earlier.

Comment: My mistake. One of them was supposed to be DEL_TIME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determine the unique column name prefixes (e.g. 'SH' or 'DEL') and combine the respective date / time columns with a space as separator. Parse the combined [to datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).

```
pfxs = df.columns.to_series().str.replace('_TIME', '').str.replace('_DATE', '').unique()

for p in pfxs:
    if f'{p}_DATE' in df.columns and f'{p}_TIME' in df.columns:
        df[f'{p}_DATETIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df[f'{p}_DATE']+' '+df[f'{p}_TIME'])
```

```
df
      SH_DATE    DEL_DATE  ...         SH_DATETIME        DEL_DATETIME
0  2020-04-22  2020-04-27  ... 2020-04-22 19:42:00 2020-04-27 19:11:00
1  2020-04-22  2020-04-25  ... 2020-04-22 19:42:00 2020-04-25 19:26:00
2  2020-04-24  2020-04-24  ... 2020-04-24 09:55:00 2020-04-24 09:55:00
3  2020-04-24  2020-04-26  ... 2020-04-24 14:27:00 2020-04-26 14:27:00
```

To make this somewhat fail-safe, you can add checks to make sure a date *and* a time column exists for given prefix before attempting to combine.

In case some elements in your date & time columns cannot be parsed to datetime, setting `errors='coerce'` might be an option, leaving you with `NaT` for elements that fail to parse, e.g.

```
pd.to_datetime(df[f'{p}_DATE']+' '+df[f'{p}_TIME'], errors='coerce')
```

in the code above.

Comment: ```unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'``` I reckon I should convert all the columns to strings before running your suggestion?

Comment: @Saurus hm from your example, I assumed the date/time columns were string already. Which line exactly throws the error (can you add the traceback to the question)?

Comment: After converting them all to strings, before the concat, I get the error: ```ParserError: month must be in 1..12: 0 0```

Comment: @Saurus yes, seems like not all your _DATE and _TIME columns contain elements formatted like e.g. `2020-04-27` or  `19:42:00` respectively. You'll need to clean first, but hard to tell *how* without knowing the exact content

Comment: Yes, the feature size on this dataset is large, so I missed couple of columns which were boolean. How would you add an exception to above code? So to exclude certain columns?

Comment: Also, how to inspect dtypes of a frame-series? For instance with a dataframe you can do a df.info(). ``` cols = df.filter(like='TIME').columns ´´´ then ``` cols.info() ´´´

Comment: @Saurus you could add [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) checks but I doubt this will give satisfactory results. Python isn't strictly typed, most objects can be converted to string but not all strings can be converted to datetime. Another option might be a [try/except](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) to catch parser errors. But that's just *guessing* without knowing the actual content you have to handle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239187/discussion-between-saurus-and-mrfuppes).